# SQL Server query never completing when a column in included

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

We've just come across a rather weird issue with SQL Server 2017. We have a query which should be returning around 60 rows. However it never completes. Experimenting in Management Studio, we get the same behaviour as the application which normally executes this query.

We've tracked the issue down to a single column called `Descr`, an `nvarchar(100)` column. It's not being filtered on. I.e it doesn't appear in a `WHERE` clause. It's not a calculated column. It's just a plain old `nvarchar` containing descriptions.

If we comment out the column from the select, the query finishes instantly. So obviously something weird is going on with the column. But what?

If we include `left(Descr, 1)` as a column, then the query completes instantly.

If we include `left(Descr, 100)`, it never completes.

Obviously we can't use the query plan as the query is not completing.
At a loss here.

Any ideas/suggestions of stuff we can investigate/try out?

Comment: Without the query, or even an attempt of an [mre], what are you expecting from us here?

Comment: have you tried with a top clause? e.g. select top 10 * from myTable and increase till it hangs then investigate the row causing the issue?

Comment: Did you check the wait type (or if you’re being blocked) in sys.dm_exec_requests? Also see [why is my query slower than yesterday](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204565/why-is-my-query-suddenly-slower-than-it-was-yesterday).

Comment: The likely cause is different query plans. If you need help troubleshooting, upload the estimated execution plan of the good/bad plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question. Also, include table DDL in your question.

Comment: As I outlined in my question, the query is essentially irrelevant. If we include a single text column, it never completes. If we don't include it, it completes immediately. Including the column but performing an operation on it, like left() also allows for immediate execution. This implies it is related to either the table definition (pretty standard as far as I can see) or column content. I was looking for ideas on things which may cause this type of behaviour as it seems to be content related.

Comment: *This implies it is related to either the table definition* ... yet you have still ommitted this, and the query, despite being asked for it already. *the query is essentially irrelevant* - assumption is what often creates an XY problem.

Comment: We need to see the query, the table *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. We cannot answer this otherwise. I'm guessing there is a good index, but does not cover that column, therefore it requires a full table scan. The query is **not** irrelevant, because it's very dependent which columns you are selecting as to which index can service that query. See eg https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/10/how-to-think-like-the-sql-server-engine-adding-a-nonclustered-index/

Comment: We've just found that the table containing the description column had multiple indexes which included the description as an extra field (!!no idea why, this db is not our creation). Removing one of them has cured the problem. I'm no more enlightened as to why this should work but it has worked.

Comment: @charleface the problem was that we couldn't get the query plan - it never completed, hence we were working blind.

Comment: selecting the text in SSMS plus control-L gives you the query plan without running the query.

Comment: @Ian, although the actual plan is preferred, I specifically asked for the estimated plan instead knowing you cannot get the actual plan until it completes. Even with your work-around, you still don't have an answer because more details are needed. Again, the plan must be different.

Comment: Please please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info With respect, your question betrays a misunderstand of how all this SQL stuff actually performs, and why. It's all in the details of queries and indexes. Why do you think BigCo database administrators make bank?

Comment: I have to admit that I was unaware that I could get an estimated query plan. Hence when the query couldn't be simplified with where clauses i was left scratching my head as to how to debug this. Its the first time I've seen something as odd as this in years.

Comment: As I said, this is really not odd at all. For example, if you have an index `(WhereCol) INCLUDE (SelectCol1)` then a query `SELECT SelectCol1 FROM Table WHERE WhereCol = 123` can be satisfied with that index, whereas the query `SELECT SelectCol1, SelectCol2 FROM Table WHERE WhereCol = 123` cannot, it can only be satisfied either with a key lookup (basically a self-join against the clustered index) or a full scan of the clustered index. Depending on statistics, the compiler may decide a full scan is cheaper than 1000s of key lookups. We need to see indexes and the plan to know for sure.